# The colors blue and golden (yellow-orange) and the human eye / brain

Tags: brain, eyes

Many years ago I read a review in an article about why we love for example Lapis Lazuli so much. The article stated that there are two specific colors, yellow as golden (when it glows or shines) and a very certain type of blue (the one of Lapis Lazuli) or also a shiny dark blue. I think we are not talking about the way those are absorbed in the eye but rather which color has the biggest impact on our eyes. Like often we say red is a warning color and we see red as most 'aggresive' color this article stated that in fact this type of blue and gold is the one that causes the strongest respond in the human brain. They also added a chart back then where you could see this 'response' for each wavelenght.

I was unabled however to find anything related. I don't think it has to do with the absorption peaks of the human eye, the graph looked a bit different. Has anyone heard about this before?